# What is Android "optimising" during restarts?

Tags: android, optimization, apk, device, restart

First question, appreciate some guidance.  I am currently teaching myself to develop for Android and have installed my app (via Studio after builds) onto my own phone.

Every now and then my phone will restart itself (not querying that - these things happen).

During these (occasional) restarts I will get a message that Android is "Optimising App 1 of 1".  I am pretty sure it is my app being "optimised".

I have searched here and the Web.  Most of the questions seem to be users that have recently upgraded OS Version and that is causing the issue.  There seems to be anecdotal evidence that wiping the cache cures this and that it only does it while the device is being charged.

However, if it is my app, I don't want users of my to go through this.  I suspect it relates to the Target SDK I am using but it might be something different?

So, what is Android optimising?  How can I make best efforts to stop my app being the cause of this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your Mobile belongs to which OS version

Comment: Hi Ruban, my phone OS is 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier Android OS used to run on Dalvik Runtime which means apps used to compile at the time of execution. But now, Android has switched to ART with Lollipop version. It means all the apps will be compiled beforehand making them launch faster. So "Optimizing the Apps" basically means Android is compiling all the apps.

Answer (score 0):

**From Android 5.0, Android uses ART instead of DVM So every time your mobile OS upgraded This will happen. Also “Optimizing app” should happen only once after OS upgrade. If it’s happening every time then there is some issue in your mobile.**

> A factory reset should be probably solving this. (You have to go
>   through the pains of redownloading all your apps etc).

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Understand the OS upgrade triggers app optimisation and should happen once.  But if I update my app, that will be a new install of the app and will require a re-optimise?

Comment: @TimO new apps will be compiled again after reboot